# Collapsing two for-loops out of three in OpenMP

Tags: loops, for-loop, openmp

I was checking someone else's OpenMP code and saw these three nested for-loops, where only (the first?) two of them were being collapsed:

```
#pragma omp for collapse(2)
  for(int i=0;i<nxn;i++)
  for(int j=0;j<nyn;j++)
  for(int k=0;k<nzn;k++)
  {
    rhons[is][i][j][k] += invVOL*moments[i][j][k][0];
    Jxs  [is][i][j][k] += invVOL*moments[i][j][k][1];
    Jys  [is][i][j][k] += invVOL*moments[i][j][k][2];
    Jzs  [is][i][j][k] += invVOL*moments[i][j][k][3];
    pXXsn[is][i][j][k] += invVOL*moments[i][j][k][4];
    pXYsn[is][i][j][k] += invVOL*moments[i][j][k][5];
    pXZsn[is][i][j][k] += invVOL*moments[i][j][k][6];
    pYYsn[is][i][j][k] += invVOL*moments[i][j][k][7];
    pYZsn[is][i][j][k] += invVOL*moments[i][j][k][8];
    pZZsn[is][i][j][k] += invVOL*moments[i][j][k][9];
  }
```

My question is whether it is possible to collapse all three loops? I mean I am trying to understand the logic of the developer (he is supposed to be very experienced) - why he didn't do it?

Comment: The motivation for collapsing the outer loops is to spread work more evenly  across threads. Including the inner loop in collapse would interfere with vectorization, probably preventing it unless you set simd and use a suitable compiler.

Comment: The accepted answer is wrong!

Comment: Ok, in  case these replies remain confusing, collapse(2) combines 2 outer loops and leaves the inner loop subject to the compiler settings such as auto-vectorization.  This is likely a good choice.

Answer (score 3):

You could do that, but what benefit would it bring?

Lets assume `nxn * nyn` is significantly bigger `OMP_NUM_THREADS`. So there is already loop iterations exposed to parallelize efficiently.

On the other hand, the inner loop has a high data locality. While OpenMP would likely keep that, there may be a specific optimization that the last dimension of the arrays are multiples of cache lines - so it would be unwise to split them among threads. As tim18 mentioned, possible interference with vectorization of the inner loop may become another issue when collapsing all loops.

So basically, it brings no benefit but it could potentially be bad for performance with a stupid OpenMP implementation.